# Jquery cycle not loading styles correctly on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having an issue using the JQuery Cycle plugin. I am using it to call (eventually 4, currently) 2 code blocks of content (image, linked text, and bottom navigation.) When I load the page to test, it throws off the first calling of the styles on the first slide only. The elements that are thrown off have a position:relative parameter on them. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="slide">
  <img src="images/cycle_img_test.jpg" />
  <figure class="slide_link">
  </figure>
  <p class="slidelink_text">1 View Our Reports</p>
  <img src="images/slider_arrow.png" class="link_arrow">
    <div class="slide_nav">
    </div>
      <div class="slidenav_content">
        <p class="nav_left">&lt;</p>
        <img src="images/slide_nav_current.png" />
        <img src="images/slide_nav_other.png" />
        <img src="images/slide_nav_other.png" />
        <img src="images/slide_nav_other.png" />
    <p class="nav_right">&gt;</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Js that is calling the .slideshow :

```
<script src="js/cycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade,     scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
            });
        });
</script>
```

and here is the CSS for the styles referenced :

```
.slide_link { width:217px; height:38px; background:#d2a709; opacity:.4; position:absolute; top:255px; z-index:10; }

.slidelink_text { vertical-align:center; font:bold 16px carto_bold, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; line-height:18px; letter-spacing:.01em; padding-left:35px; color:#fafafa; position:absolute; top:265px; z-index:11; }

.slide_nav { background:#3a4c5b; opacity:.6; width:605px; height:33px; position:relative; bottom:63px; left:25px; }

.slidenav_content { max-width:600; height:33px; position:relative; bottom:89px; left:35px; }

.slidenav_content img { position:relative; left:245px; }

.nav_left{ position:relative; float:left; color:#fff; }

.nav_right{ position:relative; float:right; right:395px; color:#fff; }
```

If you could offer any advice on why the cycle is loading the styles incorrectly on only the first cue of the first slide, I'd be very grateful. Or even if you can discern whether the error is in the CSS, or the Js, would definitely help.

Thanks!

Comment: $('.slideshow') does not seem to exist in your html? You can see any errors in css via wc3 validator and any js error should be available via IE.

Comment: I believe slideshow is the wrapper around the slide elements he has documented but left out but the question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody is responding, I'll give it a try:

Your question is kind of vague. But you could use [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hellosze/HuNfz/) as a reference.

As you can see, it has all elements `relative` and uses a very clear and simple layout.

Your example may not work because of a shortage of coherent parameters in the calling of the `cycle` function such that it interferes with the way you want your HTML to be displayed.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the "random" and/or "timeout" options in the slideshow plugin, you might want to try using a hack that first hides the slideshow then show it and load it. 
Ex:

```
$('.slideshow').hide();
```

Before staring the plugin. So it would goes like:

```
<script>
$('.slideshow').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.slideshow').show();
        $('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        });
    });
</script>
```

If the styles only sticks on the first panel and not on the following, then it's likely a CSS problem.